# Get white Background when I Load transparent png image in WPF rectangle background?

Tags: c#, wpf, png, imagebrush

When I load a transparent `png` image with `ImageBrush` in `WPF` Rectangle background, I get a white background behind the image. It hides all other content back to that image.

```
public void DisplayModel()
{
    Uri url = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Model/01.png");
    BitmapImage bmpimg = new BitmapImage();
    bmpimg.BeginInit();
    bmpimg.UriSource = url;
    bmpimg.EndInit();                       

    ImageBrush BrushView = new ImageBrush(bmpimg);
    BrushView.AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Right;
    BrushView.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;

    Material MaterialView = new DiffuseMaterial(BrushView);

    MeshGeometry3D mesh_view = new MeshGeometry3D();

    double Zdeep = -48;
    double x = -30;
    double y = -5;
    double xEnd = 60;
    double yEnd = 45;
    //MessageBox.Show(x.ToString()+"-"+y.ToString());
    commonObject.makeRectangle(mesh_view, new Point3D(x, y, Zdeep), new Point3D(x + xEnd, y, Zdeep), new Point3D(x + xEnd, yEnd, Zdeep), new Point3D(x, yEnd, Zdeep), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 0));

    GeometryModel3D ViewGeometry = new GeometryModel3D(mesh_view, MaterialView);
    group.Children.Add(ViewGeometry);
}
```

Here code I used and get this kind of out put:

[image: Image get white background and wall behind image is disappear because of white background]

Comment: Maybe its the background color of the window itself? Poor question, not much information, what do you expect. Give us some code, maybe an image. And maybe take more time forming your question, than i needed for this comment ;)